# Symfony: trying to retrieve a variable saved using sfContext::getInstance()

Tags: symfony1

i have these methods in module1/actions/actions.class.php:

```
public function executeMethod1(sfWebRequest $request){

  $a = 10;

  sfContext::getInstance()->set('a', $a);
  return $this->redirect('module1/method2');

}

public function executeMethod2(sfWebRequest $request){

  echo sfContext::getInstance()->get('a');

}
```

When i execute module1/method1 i get this error:

"The "a" object does not exist in the current context."

Any idea?

Javi

Answer (score 4):

The redirect is telling the browser to load another page which terminates the current action and results in a new request that has a new context.

There are three options here:

- You could use a [forward](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_skipping_to_another_action) if you want `module1/method2` to be executed as the result of the first request.
- You could use a [flash attribute](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_flash_attributes) to pass `$a` to the next request.
- You could use a [session attribute](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_user_session) if `$a` has to live beyond the next request.

**EDIT:**  You don't need the `return` statement before the redirect either.